Delphi Bytes to Single
Is this the way to convert a 4 byte array into a Single in Delphi?
type
  RFloatToBytes = packed record
    case IsFloat: Boolean of
      True: (SingleVal: Single);
      False: (ByteVals: array[0..3] of Byte);
  end;
...

function XP_BytesToSingle(const B: array of Byte): Single;
Var
  Locale: RFloatToBytes;
begin
  Locale.ByteVals[0] := B[0];
  Locale.ByteVals[1] := B[1];
  Locale.ByteVals[2] := B[2];
  Locale.ByteVals[3] := B[3];
  Result := Locale.SingleVal;
end;

I tried to find a function like
function BytesTo...
in the unit IdGlobal but no conversion is provided for float, Extended, Single.

Note though, that you don't need to name the case variable. Giving it a name will reserve memory for it, but if you only want to use the record for conversion, that is not necessary. So "... record case boolean of ..." is enough.

Your code should work as-is, but you could also use one of these:
FUNCTION XP_BytesToSingle(CONST B : ARRAY OF BYTE) : Single;
  BEGIN
    MOVE(B[LOW(B)],Result,SizeOf(Single))
  END;

or
FUNCTION XP_BytesToSingle(CONST B : ARRAY OF BYTE) : Single;
  VAR
    S : Single ABSOLUTE B;

  BEGIN
    Result:=S
  END;

You don't need the "IsFloat" field. It just takes up space in your record:
type
  RFloatToBytes = packed record
        case Boolean of
          True: (SingleVal: Single);
          False: (ByteVals: array[0..3] of Byte);
        end;


Be aware that these do not account for endianness, which you absolutely should if converting between a real and bytes. IIRC, the way a single value is stored does not necessarily correspond to the processor’s integer endianness, but I think for most modern systems it does.

@Dúthomhas: We're talking Delphi here. I think all Delphi compilers in all targets use the IEEE format for Single (and Double, and Extended), so there's no Endianness issue here, as far as I know. Just make sure that the 4 bytes are in the proper order, as specified by IEEE standard.

Thank you.
Can I use
MOVE(B[LOW(B)],Result,SizeOf(Single))
MOVE(B[LOW(B)],Result,SizeOf(Extended))
for extended ?

@GiovanniBrambilla: Both my routines will work if you replace "Single" with "Double" or "Extended" everywhere. Of course, you need to make sure that 4 (Single), 8 (double) and 10 (Extended) bytes are available. Also note that in all compiler targets except for Win32, Extended not the standard IEEE 10-byte format. In Linux/MacOS it is a 16-byte value, and in 64-bit Intel and all ARM targets, it's the same as Double.

@GiovanniBrambilla: See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Real_Types for detailed explanation of internal storage for Real types in various targets

Recent Delphi versions provide a TSingleHelper which allows direct access to the bytes of a Single:
function XP_BytesToSingle(const B: array of Byte): Single;
begin
  for var I := 0 to 3 do
    Result.Bytes[I] := B[I];
end;

